# pgSQL NOT IN, EXIST, INNER JOIN - to search differences between tables (id)

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.4

I need to find what rows (tab_a.id_taba) don't exist in tab_b in field tab_b.id_tab_a

I have two tables.  tab_a, tab_b

**tab_a fields:**
id_taba(2,3,4,5), name, name2

**tab_b fields**
id_tabb(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8), id_tab_a(0,1,2,3), field1, field2,

When I search

```
SELECT * FROM tab_a WHERE id_taba NOT IN (SELECT id_tab_a FROM tab_b)
```

it doesn't work , but if in the same statement I exchange statements to:

```
SELECT * FROM tab_b WHERE id_tab_a NOT IN (SELECT id_taba FROM tab_a)
```

it shows 2 rows: '0', '1'

I'm trying to get which rows in tab_a.id_taba there is no in tab_b.id_tab_a

Please, give me a hint, and explanation, why it doesn't work.

Comment: Learn about [outer joins](http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/) to make this easier.  a full outer would show you records from both tables not in the other: assuming you limit to show only null values in one or the other.

Comment: I was trying earlier with LEFT JOIN, and set clause WHERE id_tab_a/id_taba IS NOT NULL, it still does'n work..

Comment: but I think you want where they ARE null meaning no match (example in answer of full outer join below)

Answer (score 1):

Using a full outer join you can find the way to see records in either table that don't exist in the other.

```
SELECT A.id_taba A, B.id_tab_a B
FROM tab_a A
FULL OUTER JOIN tab_b
 on A.id_taba = B.id_tab_a
WHERE a.id_taba is null or B.B.id_tab_a is null
```

if you remove the where clause you can see all records.  But since you seem to be after non-matching... use the nulls!

[CodingHorror](http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/) has a nice explanation of the joins and visual aids!

Comment: I'm looking at the page that link you pasted, it sounds reasonably, to look for NULLS in second table for ID from first table.

Thank You.